# Get the Sum result in NEGATIVE of positive integers

Tags: javascript

I am adding two numbers with jQuery and I need to get the result in NEGATIVE even if the integers are positive, i.e

```
var sum = (5 + 10);
console.log(sum)  // Expected result is -15
                  // Current result is 15
```

Tried concatenating like

```
sum = '-' + (a + b) // But since the string is being added to number it's not working the expected way.
```

Need a little help on the same. Thanks

Comment: You expect 5 + 10 to be -15? Do you have  a typo here or do we have different understanding of '+' operations?

Comment: He says that he need the result to be negative, I think `expected` in the code comment was a poor choice of words.

Answer (score 2):

The negative sign `-` is a valid operator in Javascript, so there is no need to use it as a string.

You can do:

```
var sum = -(5 + 10);
```

Which is how you would declare a negative number:

```
var negativeNumber = -123;
```

Grouping has the highest [precedence of any operators in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), so your addition would be done first, and then the subtraction would be applied.

---

Or if you want it to look nicer mathematically you could multiply by a negative one:

```
var sum = (5 + 10) * -1;
```

---

As [@Hanky 웃 Panky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1570534/hanky-%EC%9B%83-panky) points out in his answer, you might want to check to see if your sum is already negative, before applying a negation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `-` as string, when you use `'-'` with `+` operator, the number is casted to string and the result will be `'-15'` as string. In this case `+` operator is used as string concatenation operator.

Using `'-'` in the expression, you're not using this as operator, it is string. Use `-` without quotes to use it as arithmetic minus operator.

```
var sum = -(a + b); // -15
```

This will give you the negated result. If the result of the expression is itself negative e.g. `(-10 + 5)` above expression will give you result `5`.

In case if you always want the negative result

```
var sum = -(a + b) >= 0 ? (a + b) : -(a + b);
```

Comment: Please consider adding comments when downvoting

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with simple multiplication of result with -1.

```
var num_1 = 10;
var num_2 = 20;
var Negative = -1

var result = (parseInt(num_1) + parseInt(num_2)) * Negative;
```

The output would be -30

Comment: What about `var num_1 = -10;`

Comment: @Hanky:  It just to ensure that the output must be negative. This one is not real world scenario. In that case the number might be comes from server side and result needs to be modified as per the need.

Comment: Yes but this does not ensure that it will be negative. If one of the operands is negative your output wil be positive.